# amChart CategoryAxes with icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, amcharts

I was wondering if there's a way to add images to the CategoryAxes in amChart.

I found a demo that can include images in each graph, but these are always near the graph and/or given an offset of them, but I need to have those images stay on top of the chart.

I tried to give an `<img src ="">` to the category field on the CategoryAxes, but it displays only text, showing all the tag.

I read the methods and options this category can have, but I didn't find anything that says it can haves images displayed, so, it's possible to add them?

Add:

```
//Doesn't works the "category" option
"dataProvider": [
    "category": "<img src='link_to_image.png'>",
    "column-1": 120.99,
    //other values...
    "myBullet1": "<img src='link_to_image.png'>" //this with graph works, but doesn't puts it on top of the chart
],
"graphs": [
    "customBulletField": "myBullet1",
    "bulletOffset": 20,
    "bulletSize": 34,
    //other values
],
//other options
```

Comment: It's not possible to change the categoryAxis labels into anything other than plain strings using the given APIs. (I don't get it either, why it is limited to string) What you could do (although it is not very pretty) is, making some kind of unique id in the [labelFunction](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#labelFunction) and replace it with DOM manipulation after the chart is drawn.

Comment: @gerric Hi, I contacted with amChart support yesterday asking this question, and I got a response from them today, making this possible. All this it's very tricky, because you need to know very well how the plugin works. I'll leave the answer with the jsFiddle they gave me. For what I needed. I just had to play with offsets of labels and from the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the support from amCharts answered me making this question possible. Here I leave the jsFiddle for those who needs this in the future:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpq1xfyr/1/) Demo by amCharts

```
...
img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', 'http://www.amcharts.com//lib/3/images/1.gif');
```

In this line, as it's inside a for loop, you can have a set of images in an array, then with a counter that you can make it increment you can put the image you need in each category axis.